# ‘Not Found’ error when deploying Shiny app to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, flexdashboard

I would greatly appreciate help with tricky ‘Not Found’ error in shinyapps.io deployment.

Would you please see:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/not-found-error-when-deploying-to-shinyapps-io-whereas-app-deployed-well-hours-ago-and-still-does-locally/46029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** On Github, I noticed that the `rmarkdown` package (essential to Flexdashboard-Shiny apps) had been updated just these days (to v1.18). Therefore, I tried to deploy my app after installing the previous `rmarkdown` version,

`require(devtools); install_version("rmarkdown", version = "1.17", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

and the error vanished!

For a follow-up from the developers, please see https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1714.